# pagination broken because wordpress is adding index.html

Tags: pagination

in my blog, for some reason the pagination links look like this:

http://www.example.com/blog/page/2/index.html

and that link does not work. However this link works:

http://www.example.com/blog/page/2/

how do i fix this (either by changing the .html url or by making it work)?

you can see a live example of this bug here:

http://www.honordiaries.com/blog/

Comment: Are you using any piece of code that adds `index.html` to your url

Comment: @PieterGoosen I'm only using W3 Total Cache, but i'm not sure if it's related.

Comment: Has anything changed in your .htaccess to add that?

Comment: Cache plugins are usually the culprit.